# Transform sync httpURLConnection to async HttpClient

Tags: java, asynchronous, client-server

I have a synchronous code based on httpURLConnection, and I have to convert it to the asynchronous mode. 
Basic synchronous mode is fully functional, it works properly. To make it in the asynchronous way I am trying to use HttpClient with sendAsync method (JDK11). But I am stuck.

The summory of the project, as follows:
1) Several test classes, that extend abstractAPITest class.
2) This abstractAPITest class has the function of establishing the connection, and now I am working on it.
3) class User that invokes test classes
4) Main class that creates User instances in several threads and runs them.

Probably I should move the open connection function into User class or into main class? idk.

Here is what I have originally (sync):

```java
byte[] sendRequest(JSONObject jsonObject, String username, String password) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(this.apiUrl)).openConnection();
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()));
        }
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.write(jsonObject.toString().getBytes());
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        log.info("REST send: JSONObject");
        if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            log.error("REST send error");
            throw new IOException();
        } else {
            byte[] responseBody = null;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                data.append(line);
                responseBody = data.toString().getBytes();
            }
            br.close();
            return responseBody;
        }
    }
```

and what I have as async:

```java
byte[] request = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();

        String userPassword;
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        } else {
            throw new NullPointerException("No username and/or password.");
        }

        byte[] responseBody = null;
        byte[] request = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();

        var client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

        var httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI(apiUrl))
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes()))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(request))
                .build();

        HttpResponse.BodyHandler<String> bodyHandler = HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString();

        CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> future = client.sendAsync(httpRequest, bodyHandler);
        future.thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .join();

        byte[] responseBody = null; // DON'T PAY ATTENTION 
        return responseBody;        // TO THESE TWO LINES
    }

    private static String basicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
        String userPassword = null;
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        }
        return "Basic " + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userPassword.getBytes());
    }
```

So I need this async method do the same as sync method does, but asynchronously. So what can I do next?

Comment: "I need this async method do the same as sync method does" - do you mean you want the async method to return array of bytes? then what is the sense to use async I/O? The time and memory consumption would be the same as for sync method. If you use async I/O, your method should return Future.

Comment: Yeah, it should return Future, but I don't know how to realise that in code. What I showed above is the final point I could make. See, there is a CompletableFuture future in my code, that must get the result of client.sendAsync() method. But what should I do next - that is the problem) The async method should do the same that sync method does, but asynchronously. It turns JSON Object into the byte array and sends it to the server, then it receives the answer from the server that is also a JSON Object.

Comment: just return the value of that future variable, and let the caller have freedom to do the rest.

Comment: I don't know hot to do that(

Comment: "return future;", that's it. And change the declaration of return type of method "sendRequest" to CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>>.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Changing return type to CompletableFuture... ruins the other classes code. And I can't return a future - response body is always null. I suppose, the program should create a callback in a free thread when it sends a request, and this callback should wait for the response, while the other program continues running, and then when the response comes, the callback is to realise some more code, and then close. But how to realise that? That's the problem.

Comment: earlier you wrote: "Yeah, it should return Future". You should decide how big will be the asynchronous part of your program. Having only small part of the program asynchronous has no sense: it requires more complex programming but does not save time or memory.

Comment: Saving time or memory is not important. I need a program that sends async requests to a server and imitates multiple users connections for testing the server's productivity. Actually, I don't know which part I should make asynchronous. I suppose that it must be only request/response class, and several "users" can just run in several threads of main class. Can we switch to Russian, by the way? Or it is forbidden here?)

Comment: duplicate your question on https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java/

Comment: already did)) there were no replies) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993831/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-httpurlconnection-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5